# Unsure about the time complexity in the code

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I have a question about time complexity

```
import math

def power_iter(x,n) :
    for i in range(math.floor(math.log2(n))):
        x = x*x
        print(x)
    return math.pow(2,(n-math.pow(2,math.floor(math.log2(n)))))*x


print(power_iter(2,10))
```

Q1. Is the time complexity of **math.floor(math.log2(n))** and **n-math.pow(2,math.floor(math.log2(n))))** O(1)?

Q2. I think that this code's time complexity is O(log2(n)). Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. Are the "math.floor(math.log2(n))" and "n-math.pow(2,math.floor(math.log2(n))))" time complexity is O(1) each other? or not include in time complexity

Correct, these operations are ultimately irrelevant in the simplified time complexity. Big O notation describes the *rate of increase*, in this case with respect to *n*. The iteration over the `range` object is what you're after here; you can effectively treat the individual `math` calls within each iteration as you would basic operators on integers with O(1) time.

> Q2. I think that this code's time complexity is O(log2(n)). Is this right?

Yes.

Comment: I think your statement is not quite correct, as math.pow has a runtime of O(log(n)) for integers. So it also increases with n and should hence be included. Although in this specific example it does not change the overall complexity.

Comment: I don't quite understand, where does O(N) appear here?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Q1: It depends on the scale of `n`, but normally, you can suppose that the time complexity of the floor and log functions are in `Theta(1)`.

Answer to Q2: As you found, we have only one loop with the size of `log(n)`. So, if we assume the answer to the first question is right, you can say the time complexity is in `O(log(n))` and, also `Theta(log(n))`.